# Apache Camel CXF Endpoint - how to specify soap operation?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-camel, cxf

I have a wsdl with two soap actions. So, i've genereated java classes from it, and now there is an interface:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "...", name = "...")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface RequestsService {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "sendErrorReportResponse", targetNamespace = "...", partName = "result")
    public SendErrorReportResponse sendErrorReport(
        @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "sendErrorReport", targetNamespace = "...")
        SendErrorReport parameters
    );

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "bookRequestResponse", targetNamespace = "...", partName = "result")
    public BookRequestResponse bookRequest(
        @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "bookRequest", targetNamespace = "...")
        ServiceRequestMessage parameters
    );
}
```

Then, I've created the CXF endpoint for this interface:

```
@Bean
public CxfEndpoint myEndpoint() {
    CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
    cxfEndpoint.setAddress("...");
    cxfEndpoint.setServiceClass(RequestsService.class);
    cxfEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.POJO);
    cxfEndpoint.setLoggingFeatureEnabled(true);
    return cxfEndpoint;
}
```

And the route:

```
public static final String ENDPOINT = "cxf:bean:myEndpoint";

    @Autowired
    private MyProcessor processor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("quartz2://report?cron=0+*+*+*+*+?")
                .process(processor)
                .to(ENDPOINT);
    }
```

My question is, how can I specify to invoke one of my soap actions - sendErrorReport or bookRequest?

P.S
This code works fine for bookRequest method, when i remove sendErrorReport method from wsdl and reported classes. Otherwise, this exception comes out:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Part {http://...} parameters should be of type SendErrorReport, not ServiceRequestMessage
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.checkPart(DataWriterImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:220)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set the operation in your endpoint URI:

`ENDPOINT = "cxf:bean:myEndpoint?defaultOperationName=sendErrorReport"`

And/Or you can set the `operationName` Camel header to the required value

`.process(processor)
.setHeader("operationName", constant("sendErrorReport"))
.to(ENDPOINT);`

Note that in both cases your processor will need to create an instance of the appropriate parameter type for the operation used to avoid the exception mentioned.